# How to escape double quotes for jasper report?

Tags: csv, escaping, jasper-reports

I'm working on a piece of code, which prepares a CSV-String for jasper in java. Each time when csv-data contains double quotes i get error: **net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Misplaced quote found at position...**. Is it possible to escape the quotes programmatically? Or only in template/script file? I've tried u/0022 without success.

with Regards

Rafal Ziolkowski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to enclose the whole value in double quotes and escape double quotes in the data as a pair of double quotes.

E.g. if you have `a "b" c` in the data you'll need to put `"a ""b"" c"` in the CSV.

Comment: Thank you!  This is a functionning and simple solution. I'm working very seldom with CSV, and I've failed to check the escaping rules of csv-files.